# How to disable Password Prompt for select apps

Tags: password, administrator

How can I disable administrator password requirement for select apps, for example the app "Mac DaddyX" will not require a password to be entered to operate the desired function (in my case... changing MAC address).

Just to note that the password prompt is popping up because of macOS and NOT the app itself.

Comment: *greetings wont come up*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to bypass the requirement for administrator password unless the application in question supports remembering the password.

This is because the password is required in order to achieve what you are trying to do and macOS doesn't support bypassing security. Potentially it would be possible to run the application as the root (administrator) user and this might help, but this isn't advisable, and it seems likely that the app would still require your password.

You could do this by running the application from Terminal and prefixing the command with `sudo`.

Comment: but every time it will prompt a password or doing sudo is a one time thing?

Comment: There is no one time solution if the application you are using doesn't support that, you could contact the developer to see if they plan to add that feature in future.